# Unable to configure throttle-limit in a multithreaded step execution using spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I m trying to configure multi threaded step. I have followed the spring batch documentation.

**My Job configuration:**

```
<job id="ordinaryJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" job-repository="jobRepository">
 <step id="Ordinary" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"> 
   <tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"> 
      <chunk **throttle-limit="10**" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" reader="itemReader"                               writer="EmployeeWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
   </tasklet> 
  </step>
</job>
```

When i executing the job i m getting the below exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 49 in XML document from class path resource [xmlJob.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'throttle-limit' is not allowed to appear in element 'batch:chunk'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at controller.XMLJobController.<init>(XMLJobController.java:42)
    at controller.XMLJobController.main(XMLJobController.java:48)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'throttle-limit' is not allowed to appear in element 'batch:chunk'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processAttributes(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 15 more
```

I am able to execute the job without throttle-limit parameter. I want to know why i am not able to add. and what is concurrency limit property in task executor.

Thanks,
Sivaprakash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you investigate [Spring Batch xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd) it says that `throttle-limit` is an attribute that can be used with `tasklet` type, not with `chunk`

The SAXParseException you get says the same: throttle-limit is not expected in batch:chunk

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute
>   'throttle-limit' is not allowed to appear in element 'batch:chunk'.

The same is true with the task-executor attribute it also belongs to the tasklet, not the chunk

So, the correct usage would be

```
<tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" throttle-limit="10" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor"> 
    <chunk reader="itemReader" writer="EmployeeWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
</tasklet>
```

Comment: Hi i found this post https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-1392 They are saying its a bug in spring batch. Please confirm.

Comment: That bug was solved years ago. Why did not you tried my Solution?

Comment: Hi Serkan Arıkuşu, Sorry for the confusion, the problem is actually with .xsd which was refering to another wrong one. Its solved now. Thanks you :)